# Can't display UIImage from UIImagePickerController when using IBAction

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I 'm new to xcode. I try to select an image from the `UIImagePickerController` and
then display this image pressing a button. But the simulator crashes.
In the **.h** I use

```
UIImage *dispimage; //in order to make a global image
-(IBAction) open;
-(IBAction) print;
```

In the **.m** I have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
dispimage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];   
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(IBAction) open{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
    [imagePicker release];
};
-(IBAction) print{
imageView.image=dispimage;
};
```

When the button "print" is pressed, the sdk crashes. :(
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to get images from UIImagePickerController

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
     self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
     self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
     self.imgPicker.delegate = self; 
     self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
     dispimage = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]retain];
     [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}

-(IBAction)open
{
    if(self.imgPicker == nil)
    { 
         self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
         self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
         self.imgPicker.delegate = self; 
         self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }
    [self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES]; 
    [self.imagePicker release]; 
}

-(IBAction) print
{ 
      if(dispimage != nil)
      {
            imageView.image=dispimage; 
      }
};
```